# Getting the value of the bg property of a Label in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have been learning ui programming with Tkinter and I have gotten pretty far. I can configure/change text, `fg`, and `bg` properties of a Label, but I don't know how to obtain the `bg` property of the `Label`.

Is there some way I could save the `bg` value of a Tkinter Label into a variable, in order to compare it with other values?

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I don't have access to my PC right now, but I will try it when I do.

Comment: I turned my comment into a full-fledged answer. And accidentally deleted my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cget()`:

`label.cget('background')`

or you can treat your label like a dictionary:

`label['background']`

Example:

```
from Tkinter import *

main = Tk()
l = Label(main, text = "Label", background = "lime")
l.pack()

if l["background"] == 'lime':
    print "Lime!"
if l.cget("background") == 'lime':
    print "Still Lime!"

main.mainloop()
```

Console output:

```
Lime!
Still Lime!
```

Comment: D'oh, I forgot widgets support direct indexing. Ok, you win :-)

Comment: Yeah, `cget()` is nice, but I think direct indexing is more 'pythonic'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `cget` method to get the value of a widget's attributes. Example:

```
if my_widget.cget("background") == "red":
    print "The widget is red"
```

Comment: Thanks! This will help out. There were 2 answers and I would have checked them both, but I can onll check 1. Bot anwers help me.